# Count number of Regular Expression Matchees in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I would appreciate any help in trying to count the number of matches of a regular expression function in SAS. I need to count the number of times a financial transaction is present in a text string.

I have been able to write the expression to find the transactions but have not been able to count how many times it may appear in a string. For illustration, I have created the following table:

```
DATA Transactions;
    infile datalines dlm='  ';
    INPUT ID STRING $40.;
    DATALINES;
1   One transaction R$250
2   One instance of R$ 250 and one of R$ 200
3   Nothing to see here R$
;
RUN;
```

And I have created a variable which can check if a transaction is present.

```
DATA Want;
    Set Transactions;
    QtdMatch = PRXMATCH("/ R\$ ?\d+/",String);
RUN;
```

However, what I need to have is a variable counting the number os transactions. So, in the first string the variable would read 1, for the 2nd string 2 and for the final example 0. My strings could contain up to 50 transactions which would need to be counted.

Comment: So you're looking for the pattern of `R$### `or `R$ ###` but not `R$`?  Can we assume the R is always there? And that there should always be a number following it? Could there be more than one space between the dollar sign and amount?

Comment: I intend to make the pattern a little more complicated in the future, to identify transactions with thousands or millions in the future. But it should always have the R$ symbol. These transactions are reported manually, so there could be all kinds of mistakes such as more than one space between the dollar sign and the digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through all the matches using `call prxnext`. [This solution is adapted from the SAS documentation on CALL PRXNEXT](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n1obc9u7z3225mn1npwnassehff0.htm#n0cuqlohpjdn1bn1t25xqxxz871t).

```
data want;
    set transactions;

    regex        = prxparse("/ R\$ ?\d+/");
    stop         = length(string);
    transactions = 0;

    call prxnext(regex, 1, stop, string, position, length);

    do while (position > 0);
        transactions+1;
        call prxnext(regex, 1, stop, string, position, length);
    end;
run;
```

Output:

```
ID  STRING                                      transactions
1   One transaction R$250                       1
2   One instance of R$ 250 and one of R$ 250    2
3   Nothing to see here R$                      0
```

Comment: The second option will not work if the string has any other R or $ characters in it.  The SCAN() function uses ANY of the individual characters in the delimiter list.  It works for the example because the default behavior is to treat multiple adjacent delimiters in the string as indicating only one word boundary.

Comment: Good point. I'll remove the second option.